# Default function return in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to achieve something in javascript and have been unsuccessful. Take a look at the following object

```
app.Behaviors.pageColor = {
color: 'red',
height: '200px',
width: "200px",
init: function(){

    $("div").css({
        background: this.color,
        height: this.height,
        width: this.width
    });


}
};
```

this is just a dummy object, but there are two things i can't get it to do. First, instead of $("div").css(); I'd like to have a variable that is the container the js is invoked on. Second, I'd like the init function to run without calling it... so if the data-behavior attribute is matched and the js is add'ed to my behaviours, it will run the init function. To explain my behaviours talk, this is how all my JS comes together.

```
// Create the object
var app = window.app || {};

// Create the Behaviors object to store methods
app.Behaviors = {}

// Creates methods of the Behaviors object
app.LoadBehavior = function(context){
if(context === undefined){
    context = $(document);
}
context.find("*[data-behavior]").each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    var behaviors = me.attr('data-behavior');

    $.each(behaviors.split(" "), function(index,behaviorName){
        try{
            var BehaviorClass = app.Behaviors[behaviorName];
            var initalizedBehavior = new BehaviorClass(me);
        }
        catch(e){
            // No Operation
        }
    }); // each
}); // find 
}; // LoadBehavior function

// Call the ready function
$(document).ready(function(){
app.LoadBehavior();

/*** Call this init when the behavior is found, not by declaring it here. ***/
app.Behaviors.pageColor.init();

//Debugging
console.log(app);
});
```

So this creates a Behaviours object for me to access, based on what data-behavoirs attributes it finds.

Please ask if you have any questions or need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create this as a jQuery plugin? Then you can call on any collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I considered the plugin idea (elclanrs) and i read on those mozilla docs (andrew), thanks!

I'll show you what i've come up with. So all i've changed is the document ready in application.js

```
// Call the ready function
$(document).ready(function(){

// Run the above function
app.LoadBehavior();

// Look for an init function in objects.
$.each(app.Behaviors, function(key, value){

    //If
      // The Behavoir is an object
      // The data-behavior matching the object is found in the dom
      // The object has an init function
    if($.type(value) === 'object' && $("*[data-behavior="+key+"]").length && jQuery.isFunction(value.init) ){
        return value.init(key);
    }

}); //each

});
```

So this find's any objects in the behaviors object and i'm testing because you can do it like andrew said and use a function which will run when called anyways. Then it looks for an init function and run's it.

This way, I can use literal notation objects (which i like personally / was my goal here).

Question: Does anything look weird about my if statement inside the each? I can't think of any pitfalls with this but i would love for any critique. my app.js and object.js have stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than an object, you want to write a *function* that's called when you create the object as you do when you call `var initalizedBehavior = new BehaviorClass(me);`. This is Javascript's version of object-oriented programming. It will look like this:

```
app.Behaviors.pageColor = function(selector) {
  // These were your properties:
  this.color = 'red',
  this.height = '200px';
  this.width = "200px";

  // This was the `init` property:
  $(selector).css({
    background: this.color,
    height: this.height,
    width: this.width
  });
}
```

You can read more about the pattern here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript